# Big JSON record to BigQuery is not showing up

Tags: google-bigquery

I wanted to try to upload big JSON record object to BigQuery.

I am talking of JSON records of 1.5 MB each, with a complex nested schema up to 7th degree.

For simplicity, I started to load file with a single record on one line.

At first I try to have BigQuery to autodetect my schema, but that resulted in table that is not responsive and I cannot perform query on, albeit it says it had at least a record.

Then, assuming that my schema could be too hard to reverse for the loader, I tried to write the schema myself and I then I tried to load my my file with single record.

At first I got a simple error with just "invalid".

```
bq load --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON invq_data.test_table 
my_single_json_record_file
Upload complete.
Waiting on bqjob_r5a4ce64904bbba9d_0000015e14aba735_1 ... (3s) Current 
status: DONE   
BigQuery error in load operation: Error processing job 'invq-
test:bqjob_r5a4ce64904bbba9d_0000015e14aba735_1': JSON table 
encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows:
1; errors: 1.
```

Which after checking for the job error was just giving me the following:

```
"status": {
"errorResult": {
  "location": "file-00000000", 
  "message": "JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1.", 
  "reason": "invalid"
}, 
"errors": [
  {
    "location": "file-00000000", 
    "message": "JSON table encountered too many errors, giving up. Rows: 1; errors: 1.", 
    "reason": "invalid"
  }
], 
"state": "DONE"
```

},

The after a couple of more attempts creating new tables, it actually started to succeed on command line, without reporting errors:

```
bq load --max_bad_records=1 --source_format=NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON invq_data.test_table_4 my_single_json_record_file
Upload complete.
Waiting on bqjob_r368f1dff98600a4b_0000015e14b43dd5_1 ... (16s) Current status: DONE
```

with no error on the status checker...

```
  "statistics": {
    "creationTime": "1503585955356", 
    "endTime": "1503585973623", 
    "load": {
      "badRecords": "0", 
      "inputFileBytes": "1494390", 
      "inputFiles": "1", 
      "outputBytes": "0", 
      "outputRows": "0"
    }, 
    "startTime": "1503585955723"
  }, 
  "status": {
    "state": "DONE"
  },
```

But no actual records are added to my tables.

I tried to perform the same from WebUI but the result is the same. Green on the completed job, but no actual record added.

Is there something else that I can do for checking where the data is sinking to? Maybe some more log?

I can imagine that maybe I am on the the edge of the 2 MB JSON row size limit but, if so, should this be reported as error?

Thanks in advance for the help!!

EDIT:

It turned out the complexity of my schema was a bit the devil in here. 
My json files were valid, but my complex schema had several errors.

It turned out that I had to simplify it such schema anyway, because I got a new batch of data where single json instances where more 30MB and I had to restructure this data in a more relational way, whilst making smaller rows to insert in the database.

Funny enough when the schema was scattered across multiple entities (ergo, simplified) the actually error/inconsistencies of the schema started to actually show up in error returned and it was easier to fix them. (Mostly it was new nested undocumented data which I was not aware anyway... but still my bad).

The lesson here, is when a table schema is too long (I didn't experiment how much precisely is too long) BigQuery just hide itself behind reporting *too many errors* to show. 
But that is a point where you should consider simplify the schema(/structure) of your data.

Comment: looks like you still didn't get your schema correct. As it seems, you added the flag `--max_bad_records=1` so the load operation is just ignoring the single line you have in your file, that's why it outputs no errors. Maybe running the same command without this flag will keep showing you what the error might be (maybe it's the schema that needs some deeper debugging)

Comment: @WillianFuks - Your are right actually removing `--max_bad_records` give consistently a `Rows: 1; errors: 1.` with `reason": "invalid"`. But should give me a more detailed error on what field is not consistent with the schema? I had more detailed errors like that in past for example.

Comment: I agree the error message does not help much. One challenge you have in your table is that as you have 7 levels of nestings happening, debugging becomes quite more difficult. I recommend first using a [json validator](https://jsonlint.com/) and then working on your schema until you figure where the mistake is. You could also try showing us an example of the data and the schema you tried so far, we might find something.

Comment: @WillianFuks Sorry for the late reply. You were right; there were several issues in the schema. See my edit for how I solved it.